# Pandas-iterate through a dataframe column and concatenate corresponding row values that contain a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame with column1 containing string values and column 2 containing lists of sting values.[image: data description]

I want to iterate through column1 and concatenate column1 values with their corresponding row values into a new data-frame.

Say, my input is

```
`dfd = {'TRAINSET':['101','102','103', '104'], 'unique':[['a1','x1','b2'],['a1','b3','b2'] ,['d3','g5','x2'],['x1','b2','a1']]}`
```

after the operation my data will look like this

```
dfd2 = {'TRAINSET':['101a1','101x1','101b2', '102a1','102b3','102b2','103d3', '103g5','103x2','104x1','104b2', '104a1']}
```

what i tried is:

```
dg = pd.concat([g['TRAINSET'].map(g['unique']).apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1)
```

but i get **KeyError:'TRAINSET'** as this is probably not the proper syntax
.Also, I would like to  remove the Nan values in the list

Comment: Looks like `TRAINSET` is an index , you should reset the index before proceeding

Comment: I did  g.reset_index(drop=False)   (my actual dataframe is saved as 'g') and tried running

Comment: dont use drop=False just do `g= g.reset_index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible use list comprehension with flatten values of lists, join values by `+` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor is necessary:

```
#if necessary
#df = df.reset_index()

#flatten values with filter out missing values
L = [(str(a) + x) for a, b in df[['TRAINSET','unique']].values for x in b if pd.notna(x)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'TRAINSET': L})
print (df1)
   TRAINSET
0     101a1
1     101x1
2     101b2
3     102a1
4     102b3
5     102b2
6     103d3
7     103g5
8     103x2
9     104x1
10    104b2
11    104a1
```

Or use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+), crete default index, remove missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and join columns to `+` with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for one column `DataFrame` :

```
df = df.explode('unique').dropna(subset=['unique']).reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = (df['TRAINSET'].astype(str) + df['unique']).to_frame('TRAINSET')
print (df1)
   TRAINSET
0     101a1
1     101x1
2     101b2
3     102a1
4     102b3
5     102b2
6     103d3
7     103g5
8     103x2
9     104x1
10    104b2
11    104a1
```

Comment: for this solution i get 
KeyError: "['TRAINSET'] not in index"

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - First use `df = df.reset_index()` before my solution

Comment: I guess missing values is the reason my sol didnt work. Nice 1 for thinking that +1

Answer (score 2):

Coming from your original data you can do the below using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (*new in pandas -0.25+*) and [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

Input:

```
dfd = {'TRAINSET':['101','102','103', '104'], 
 'unique':[['a1','x1','b2'],['a1','b3','b2'] ,['d3','g5','x2'],['x1','b2','a1']]}
```

---

Solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dfd)
df.explode('unique').astype(str).agg(''.join,1).to_frame('TRAINSET').to_dict('list')
```

---

```
{'TRAINSET': ['101a1',
  '101x1',
  '101b2',
  '102a1',
  '102b3',
  '102b2',
  '103d3',
  '103g5',
  '103x2',
  '104x1',
  '104b2',
  '104a1']}
```

Comment: This gives me a data-frame like this:                            {'TRAINSET': ['TC104',
  'TC101',
  'TC266.... what i want is TNST101TC104,TNST101TC101,TNST101TC268

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami can you do the same after doing `df = df.reset_index()` ? i.e after resetting the index, right now the other column is an index I suppose

Comment: if i do that the error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str comes up
from line 3 df1 = (g['TRAINSET'].astype(str) + g['unique']).to_frame('TRAINSET')

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami it shouldnt as `.astype(str)`  in the code should take care of that , but i see you have found your answer :)

Comment: your code is much more pythonic in nature although it outputs a df that is 
like this: {'TRAINSET': ['TC104', 'TC101', 'TC266.... but what i want is TNST101TC104,TNST101TC101,TNST101TC268

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami even after you do `df = df.reset_index()` and then use `df.explode('unique').astype(str).agg(''.join,1).to_frame('TRAINSET').to_dict('list')` ? off got it there might ne nan as jez pointed

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, just to give you some choice...

```
import pandas as pd

_dfd = {'TRAINSET':['101','102','103', '104'], 'unique':[['a1','x1','b2'],['a1','b3','b2'] ,['d3','g5','x2'],['x1','b2','a1']]}

dfd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(_dfd)
dfd.set_index("TRAINSET", inplace=True)

print(dfd)


dfd2 = dfd.reset_index()

def refactor(row):
    key, l = str(row["TRAINSET"]), str(row["unique"])
    res = [key+i for i in l]
    return res


dfd2['TRAINSET'] = dfd2.apply(refactor, axis=1)
dfd2.set_index("TRAINSET", inplace=True)
dfd2.drop("unique", inplace=True, axis=1)

print(dfd2)
```

Comment: TypeError: ('can only concatenate str (not "float") to str', 'occurred at index 0')  
comes at the line dfd2['TRAINSET'] = dfd2.apply(refactor, axis=1)

Comment: @DevarshiGoswamiI edited to put a full working example

Comment: dfd2['TRAINSET'] = dfd2.apply(refactor, axis=1) line still throws 
TypeError: ('can only concatenate str (not "float") to str', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami Are you sure, you used the latest version of code? As said, I updated the example to for ce string conversion prior to concatenation.